# Railo server converts plus (+) to spaces

Tags: railo, cfml

Weird thing I noticed on my Railo server.
All `+` characters I pass in the url are automatically converted to spaces when I `cfdump` or `cfoutput` them.

Any server setting to change so that a `+` will remain a `+`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Railo is not converting the `+` characters to space - your browser is.

(If you run the exact same code on ColdFusion you will get the same behaviour.)

In URLs, `+` is a reserved character and needs to be encoded as `%2B`, and there are [several other characters that require encoding](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm) too.

You can use the CFML function [UrlEncodedFormat](http://cfdocs.org/urlencodedformat) to encode text for use in a URL.